# How to fix "-bash: bazel: command not found" when running "bazel build //src:bazel" from windows

Tags: windows, bazel

Hi I downloaded the last release of bazel 0.24.1 for windows and I did the same instructions But, when I run
`./compile.sh`
It shows the error as mentioned  and I tried `bazel build //src:bazel` but it didn't work to it shows me

> -bash: bazel: command not found
>   after searching I tried : `bazel --output_user_root=c:\tmp build //src:bazel.exe`
>   but the same error
>   -bash: bazel: command not found

Ps: I run it from msys64 any suggestions please thanks a lot for reacting

```
 ./compile.sh
```

> Building Bazel from scratch ERROR: Must specify PROTOC if not
>   bootstrapping from the distribution artifact
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- NOTE: This failure is likely occuring if you are trying to bootstrap
>   bazel from a developer checkout. Those checkouts do not include the
>   generated output of the protoc compiler (as we prefer not to version
>   generated files)
>
> .
>
> - To build a developer version of bazel, do
>
>   bazel build //src:bazel
> - To bootstrap your first bazel binary, please download a dist archive from our   release page at
>     https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases and run   compile.sh on
>     the unpacked archive.
>
> The full install instructions to install a release version of bazel
>   can be found at https://docs.bazel.build/install-compile-source.html
>   For a rationale, why the bootstrap process is organized in this way,
>   see https://bazel.build/designs/2016/10/11/distribution-artifact.html

Comment: as i mentionned this is  bazel build //src:bazel DIDN'T WORK it shows me 

the error -bash: bazel: command not found

Comment: WHAT TO DO PLEASE IT's an emergency case really !!!!